# How to style each element inside the array with css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

Would anyone be able to give an example on how to do this? I want to style it inside a box with the username in left hand corner in bold, date/time in bottom corner and comment in the middle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var comments = document.getElementById("allcomments").value; 

     //Get Storage 
                var username = window.localStorage.getItem("username");

        // Call Ajax for existing comments
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'URL.php',
        success: function(result) {
            var arr = JSON.parse(result);

            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                var obj = arr[i];

                console.log(obj);   

                var output = document.getElementById("allcomments"); 
                output.innerHTML += (obj.username + ' ' + obj.comment + ' ' + obj.commDate + ' ' + obj.sentiment + '<br>'); 

            }

        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
          <div id="content" class="content">
            <h1>Forum</h1>
                <form id="forumPost" method='POST'>
                   <textarea rows="3" col="60" name="comment" placeholder="Create a Post..." id="comment"></textarea>
                   <button><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Post' class="post"></button>
                </form>
                <p id="error" class="errormessage"></p>
                <p id="allcomments" class="postmessage"></p>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit broad i assume you want this line with some HTML and CSS   "(obj.username + ' ' + obj.comment + ' ' + obj.commDate + ' ' + obj.sentiment + '<br>')"  You didnt mention anything about obj.sentiment?

Comment: @userX I am coming back to that later, once I know how to target one element then I can do the same for the others.

Comment: Well you can start with simple <p> tags... and if you need more inspiration, copy the style of any wordpress website out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may divide each value in the object into blocks.

Your line 
`output.innerHTML += (obj.username + ' ' + obj.comment + ' ' + obj.commDate + ' ' + obj.sentiment + '<br>');` makes all values join to become a line. This is not desirable when you're going to style it like what you've mentioned.

If you are going to display results row by row, `#allcomments` is better to be a `<div>`.
Then, you should decide how the rows of results display in dom. In your case, let say the code of each row would like this:

```
<div class="comment-container">
    <div class="username"><!--obj.username--></div>
    <div class="comment"><!--obj.comment--></div>
    <div class="date"><!--obj.commDate--></div>
</div>
```

After that, style it. Something like:

```
#allcomments>.comment-container>div{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#allcomments>.comment-container .username{
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#allcomments>.comment-container .date{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Finally, change the `output.innerHTML` line. You should set the value by using the layout discussed above.

`output.innerHTML += '<div class="comment-container"><div class="username">'+obj.username+'</div><div class="comment">'+obj.comment+'</div><div class="date">'+obj.commDate+'</div></div>';`

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you so much! You explained it and showed me so clearly how to do it, I really appreciate it :)